# Menu CSS na Diagonal

Tags: html, css, ionic

Estou desenvolvendo um layout de um aplicativo mobile, que será desenvolvido no IONIC, o cliente nos enviou um exemplo, de como gostaria que fosse o menu do aplicativo, como podem ver no link abaixo:

https://dribbble.com/shots/1701001-GIF-Exercise

Poderiam me dar uma idéia de como chegar nesse resultado, do menu na diagonal, pegando toda a tela do celular?

Comment: cara, eu usei um template que faz algo parecido na diagonal, [veja aqui](https://henrique.etc.br/) esses traços na diagonal são imagens utilizadas como background. talvez vc posso fazer algo parecido.

Comment: @h3nr1ke esses traços são um unico arquivo SVG, que pega toda a tela, já é predefinido nele, eu precisaria que fosse independente, cada item do menu, como o pessoal postou abaixo... Mesmo assim, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a propriedade rotate do CSS3
abaixo segue um exemplo 
Os efeitos você pode utilizar o Jquery e Css @frame animation

No  seu thml

```
<div class='celular'>
    <div class="transversal-bg">
        <div class='bar-one rotate'>

        </div>
        <div class='bar-tow rotate'>

        </div>
        <div class='bar-three rotate'>

        </div>
  </div>
  <div class='menu-setter'>

        <div class='menu-icon'>
              Icon
        </div>
        <div class='menu-icon'>
              Icon
        </div>
        <div class='menu-icon'>
              Icon
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css Você pode adaptar fiz so um exemplo pequeno

```
.celular{float:left;width:160px;height:240px;background:pink}
.transversal-bg{float:left;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden}
.rotate {
     -ms-transform: rotate(-33deg); /* IE 9 */
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-33deg); /* Safari */
     transform: rotate(-33deg); /* Standard syntax */;
     margin-left: -50px;}
.bar-one{float:let;width:160%;height:33%;background:red}
.bar-tow{float:let;width:160%;height:33%;background:orange}
.bar-three{float:let;width:160%;height:33%;background:#00bfff}
.menu-setter{position: absolute;width: 160px;}
.menu-icon{position:relative;width:100%;text-align:center;height:33%;line-
height: 480%;}
```

**Você pode ver um  exemplo  funcionando  [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/2k9xqoy2/12/)**

Comment: Repito a mesma pergunta, como poderia deixar os itens dos menus, seguindo os fundos coloridos, pois como aplicativo, eles devem preencher 100% da tela, tanto na altura, quanto na largura...

Comment: Bom vc pode utilizar aniamação por frame no  css, jquery ou  canvas html5

Answer (score 1):

**Edite**

Essa é a solução que acredito ter o melhor resultado, tem menos código, usa só um linear-gradiente e é mais fácil para adicionar novos itens

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
.container {
 width: 15%;
 height: 80%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: linear-gradient(15deg, red 33%, yellow 33%, yellow 66%, green 66%); 
}
.container div {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 33.333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div>
  <span>item1</span>
 </div>
 <div>
  <span>item2</span>
 </div>
 <div>
  <span>item3</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Da para fazer apenas com CSS usando `skwedY()`

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
.container {
width: 25%;
height: 90%;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: tomato; 
}
.container div {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: gold;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 33.333%;
 transform: skewY(15deg);
 transform-origin: left;
}
.container div:first-of-type {
 background-color: tomato;
}
.container div:last-of-type {
 background-color: turquoise;
}
.container div > span {
 transform: skewY(-15deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div>
  <span>item1</span>
 </div>
 <div>
  <span>item2</span>
 </div>
 <div>
  <span>item3</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hugo, achei bem legal a sua solução, porém, como poderia deixar os itens dos menus, seguindo os fundos coloridos ? Eu fiz um teste no codepen, olha ai https://codepen.io/d3rsonbr/pen/bLvxgb

Comment: Não entendi direito, vc quer que o texto dos itens do menu também fiquem inclinados? Se for isso vc pode por transform: rotate(-28deg) na div

Comment: essa é a idéia: http://prntscr.com/ihgnt8

Comment: Jovem eu não sei exatamente a técnica que ele usou, mas provavelmente ele foi usando margins para posicionar os ícones, Pode ser também que esse menu funcione só para telas mobiles e no Desktop ele da outro tratamento pro Menu. Com as resposta que vc tem aqui, já da para chegar em um resultado bem próximo, só complica um pouco se vc quiser ele com 1200px de largura e com 320px de larguda e cada hora com uma altura de tela. Esse "desalinhamento" dos ícones certamente é para não deixar os ícones de cima entrem no espaço que tem a cor diferente abaixo

Comment: Sim, isso ai na verdade é só uma imagem...  foi feito no photoshop esse menu... não sei se é possivel chegar nessa exibição com CSS...